# Escape comma C# - CSV

Tags: c#, csv

I've been following some tuts on creating CSV file, but obliviously teacher has some issues in one part of code. Actually there's method which is replacing strange characters and escaping comma because it's creating CSV.

And its code looks like this:

```
private string PrepareInputForFile(string input)
{
        input = input.Replace('ı', 'i')
            .Replace('ç', 'c')
            .Replace('ö', 'o')
            .Replace('ş', 's')
            .Replace('ü', 'u')
            .Replace('ğ', 'g')
            .Replace('İ', 'I')
            .Replace('Ç', 'C')
            .Replace('Ö', 'O')
            .Replace('Ş', 'S')
            .Replace('Ü', 'U')
            .Replace('Ğ', 'G')
            .Replace(""", """") // this line is issue
            .Trim();
        if (input.Contains(","))
        {
            input = """ + input + """; // and this line also!
        }
        return input;
}
```

Actually there is error thrown which says:

> Represents text as sequence of UTF-16 code units. ; expected.

So how could I fix this code, so it might really work (Escape comma etc).

Comment: Note that while your teacher may be wanting you to write a CSV file manually as part of an exercise, this is not how it's recommended to be done in the real world. Reinventing the wheel isn't a good use of your time, and you're likely to fall into a bunch of pitfalls that have already been solved by others. Excellent libraries exist that will easily produce valid CSV files, such as [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: If you are going to do that many replace operations, use a `StringBuilder`, not just a `string`.  Something like `var buffer = new StringBuilder(input);`, then all the `.Replace` calls on the buffer, and when you are finished, convert it back to a string using `buffer.ToString();`.  Your 13 `.Replace` calls are generating 13 garbage strings.

Comment: Besides checking for a comma (,) to determine if you should add surrounding double quotes, you should also check for double quotes themselves and newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `"\""` instead of `"""` to define the character `"` as a part of a string. Your code should look like this:

```
 .Replace("\"", "\"\"") // this line is issue
```

Comment: If `input`is an string, you must asign it as: `input = "\" + input + \"";`

Comment: @pH4ngH0st No, that is wrong.  Their example will work.

Comment: Sorry, it was: input = "\"" + input + "\"";

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape double quotes in C# strings:

```cs
...
.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
...
 input = "\"" + input + "\"";
```

Comment: That's called string interpolation